# How do I compare 2 canvas elements which do not have image as code is from client side in c#

Tags: c#, canvas, automation, html5-canvas, mstest

In my automated test - I have case to compare before and after image after certain action is performed, But the problem is it is having canvas element and image is created from client side so I am not able to understand how do I compare in such scenario:

HTML Source Code:

```
<div class="canvas-container" style="width: 492px; height: 492px; position: relative; user-select: none;"><canvas _ngcontent-ctc-c5="" id="collage-canvas" class="lower-canvas" width="492" height="492" style="position: absolute; width: 492px; height: 492px; left: 0px; top: 0px; touch-action: none; user-select: none;"></canvas><canvas class="upper-canvas " width="492" height="492" style="position: absolute; width: 492px; height: 492px; left: 0px; top: 0px; touch-action: none; user-select: none; cursor: move;"></canvas></div>
```

The canvas which I need to compare

```
    //canvas[@class='upper-canvas ']
```

I'm having MSTest C# automation framework

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve and compare content of an html canvas element you can incorporate steps below:

1. Retrieve the canvas image as a base64 string using the following JavaScript code: `return arguments[0].toDataURL('image/png').substring(22);`
2. Convert to C#'s Bitmap
3. Compare any two given Bitmap instances by checking if they are equal pixel-wise.

Assuming that you are using selenium WebDriver C# for your automation, you can use code snippets below for above points:

```
  public static Bitmap GetImageFromCanvas(this IWebDriver Driver, IWebElement element)
    {
        var imageBase64 = Driver.ExecuteJavaScript<object>("return arguments[0].toDataURL('image/png').substring(22);", element);

        return ImageHelpers.ConvertBase64ToBmp(imageBase64);
    }

  public static Bitmap ConvertBase64ToBmp(object base64)
    {
        var base64String = base64.ToString();
        byte[] byteBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer);

        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        return (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(memoryStream);            
    }  

  public static bool AreEqual(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)
    {
        if (!bmp1.Size.Equals(bmp2.Size))
        {
            return false;
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < bmp1.Width; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp1.Height; ++y)
            {
                var a1 = bmp1.GetPixel(x, y);
                var a2 = bmp2.GetPixel(x, y);
                if (bmp1.GetPixel(x, y) != bmp2.GetPixel(x, y))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```